# Correctly specify the types of unpacked `zip`

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance, zip-operator

I need to restructure some lists of tuples in python. I want to put the *n*-th value of each tuple in these lists into a separate tuple. The tuples in the lists are all similarly structured (e.g. position 1 is always an `int`) and I provided the respective type hints. However, I unexpectedly receive an error message when I write the following code:

```py
test_list: list[tuple[int, str]] = [(1, 'testa'), (2, 'testb')]

a: tuple[int]
b: tuple[str]

a, b = zip(*test_list)
```

As expected, `a` and `b` now only consist of `int` and `str`, respectively:

```py
print(a)  # Output: (1, 2)
print(b)  # Output: ('testa', 'testb')
```

However, Pylance still complains about the zip expression:

```
Expression of type "tuple[int | str]" cannot be assigned to declared type "tuple[int]"
  "tuple[int | str]" is incompatible with "tuple[int]"
    Tuple entry 1 is incorrect type
      Type "int | str" cannot be assigned to type "int"
        "str" is incompatible with "int" (PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues)
Expression of type "tuple[int | str]" cannot be assigned to declared type "tuple[str]"
  "tuple[int | str]" is incompatible with "tuple[str]"
    Tuple entry 1 is incorrect type
      Type "int | str" cannot be assigned to type "str"
        "int" is incompatible with "str" (PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

What do I have to change to get rid of the error message? Or is this a bug in Pylance? Does it not recognize the star operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the problem here is with Pylance *or* your code.

### `zip` accepts generic iterables

The problem is in the way that `zip` is designed/annotated. If we look at typeshed (always a great source for figuring out types of built-in functions), we can see that the the two-argument-overload looks something like this (simplified):

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)
T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")

...

class zip(Iterator[T]):
    def __new__(cls, iter1: Iterable[T1], iter2: Iterable[T2]) -> zip[tuple[T1, T2]]: ...

    def __next__(self) -> T: ...
```

([Source](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/builtins.pyi), `zip` starting in line 1673 as of today's `main` branch)

What this means is that `zip` implements the iterator protocol (also mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)). It is in fact a *generic* iterator over a type `T` and calling `next` on an instance of such a `zip` iterator returns something of type `T`.

Moreover, the type `T` is fully specified upon construction of a `zip` instance as indicated by the `__new__` return type annotation.

The key point however is that the arguments taken by `__new__` are annotated as `Iterable`. Those are generic over only **one** type argument. In this example the first iterable is generic over type argument `T1` and the second over `T2`. The type argument to the resulting `zip` is then a `tuple[T1, T2]`.

### Tuples to iterables and back to tuples

This is totally fine, when our iterables are in fact of a "consistent" type. Take the following example:

```py
a = (1, 2)
b = ("1", "2")
x, y = zip(a, b)

reveal_type(x)
reveal_type(y)
```

Not sure how this is done with Pylance, but the `reveal_type` statements cause `mypy` to note the following:

```
note: Revealed type is "Tuple[builtins.int, builtins.str]"
note: Revealed type is "Tuple[builtins.int, builtins.str]"
```

Makes sense, considering `a` and `b` are of type `tuple[int, int]` and `tuple[str, str]` respectively, which in turn is generalized to `Iterable[int]` and `Iterable[str]` when passed to the `zip` constructor and there turned into the type argument `tuple[int, str]` for the values returned by the iterator.

### Tuples can have multiple type arguments

But what happens, if we change the setup just slightly:

```py
a = (1, "2")
b = ("1", 2)
x, y = zip(a, b)
reveal_type(x)
reveal_type(y)
```

Now we get the following from `mypy`:

```
note: Revealed type is "Tuple[builtins.object, builtins.object]"
note: Revealed type is "Tuple[builtins.object, builtins.object]"
```

To be clear, the type of `a` and `b` is still correctly inferred to be `tuple[int, str]` and `tuple[str, int]`. But when those tuples are passed to `zip` it looks at their type arguments and it needs to **join** them because it is defined on iterables of **one** type argument. And as you can see, `int` and `str` have only `object` as their closest common base.

So the iterables are seen as containing `object`, which then gives us the `zip[tuple[object, object]]`.

### Unions vs. joins, same difference

Pylance seems to use **unions** instead of joins to find the type of those iterables, which is why you get that notice about the `zip` iterator yielding `tuple[int | str]`. Might be arguably the better approach compared to that of `mypy`, but still unsatisfactory for your purposes. But I hope you see that the fundamental issue here is the same.

Tuples are special in that they are generic over a variable number of type arguments. The reasoning is supposedly that they are of fixed length and you can therefore very precisely parameterize them. Something like a `list` can be changed in length and iterators don't even have a concept of length; they can potentially yield elements forever. So it seems reasonable to only give them one type parameter.

The problems arise, when we need to view a `tuple` as an `Iterable`. And I see no way around that.

---

### Practical solutions

As for how to proceed for you, this depends on what the actual use case is. The simplest way based on your minimal example would obviously be a `type: ignore` at the moment of unpacking the `zip`:

```py
test_list: list[tuple[int, str]] = [(1, 'testa'), (2, 'testb')]

a: tuple[int]
b: tuple[str]

a, b = zip(*test_list)  # type: ignore[assignment]
```

If you are actually dealing with functions and your setup is more involved, maybe there are other ways around this problem. If you elaborate, maybe we can work something else out. Other than that, there is no shame in using duly considered `type: ignore`s in your code, when you hit the limits of the available typing system.